# Why jsoup works differently between android studio and java netbeans?

Tags: jsoup

I have this method.

```
private  static String parsePageHeaderInfo(String urlStr) throws Exception {

    String word_google  = "google";
    String word_twitter = "twitter";

    String title , description , image , content;
    image  = "";

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urlStr).userAgent("Mozilla").get();

    title = doc.title();

    if(title.equals(""))
    {
        title= doc.select("meta[property=og:title]").attr("content");
    }

    description  = doc.select("meta[name=description]").attr("content");

    if(description.equals(""))
    {
       description= doc.select("meta[name=keywords]").attr("content");
    }

    if(description.equals(""))
    {         
        description= doc.select("meta[property=og:description]").attr("content");            
    }

    if(description.equals(""))
    {
        description = title;
    }

    Elements src_img = doc.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g)]");

    if(src_img.size() > 0 )
    {
       image = src_img.first().attr("content");
    }

    if(image.equals(""))
    {
        image = doc.select("meta[property=og:image]").attr("content");
    } 

    if(image.equals(""))
    {
        src_img = doc.select("link[href~=(?i)\\.(ico)]");
        if(src_img.size() > 0 )
        {
            if(urlStr.contains(word_twitter) && image.equals(""))
            {
                image = src_img.first().attr("href");    
            }
            else
            {
                image = urlStr + src_img.first().attr("href");    
            }
        }
    }         

    if(urlStr.contains(word_google) && image.equals(""))
    {
        image = urlStr + "/images/google_favicon_128.png";
    }

    return title  +  " \n a "+ description + "  \n b" + image ;  

}

        String e = parsePageHeaderInfo("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMUDVMiITOU");
        System.out.println(e);
```

when I execute this code in android studio the output is :

```
title : YouTube.
description : YouTube.
image : https:   //www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMUDVMiITOU//s.ytimg.com/yts/favicon-vfldLzJxy.ico.
```

but in netbeans the output is :

```
title : DJ Snake, Lil Jon - Turn Down for What - YouTube.
description : Download the single on iTunes: http://smarturl.it/TD4W Director- Daniels Producer- Judy Craig Co Producer- Jonathan Wang Executive Producer- Candice Ouaknine...
image : https:   //i.ytimg.com/vi/HMUDVMiITOU/hqdefault.jpg.
```

what is the difference ? , the second options is the correct.

Comment: Try with a different user agent `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1944.0 Safari/537.36`. Also include a referrer `http://www.google.com`.

Comment: Yes, you have the reason. :)

Comment: I'm going to post it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a different user agent `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1944.0 Safari/537.36`. Also include a referrer http://www.google.com

The user agent you have provided might not be sufficient, or valid.

You can find a number of user agents [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php)